# Application not pointing to 2.x pointing to 1.2

Tags: log4j, mule-studio

Application is still point to log4j 1.2 after upgrading to log4j 2.5. find below log4j2.xml file and warnings which i got on server start up.
Based on below configurations it supposed to create log files but it is not creating.

Note:blow configurations are working in local system but not working when I am deploying in server.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <Configuration status="TRACE">
        <Properties>
            <Property name="rotateLogsInterval">6</Property>
            <Property name="log.dir">D:\\Mconnect\\LOGGER</Property>
            <Property name="log.INVALIDMNO.dir">D:\\Mconnect\\LOGGER\\INVALIDMNO</Property>
            <Property name="log.MOBINL1000.dir">D:\\Mconnect\\LOGGER\\MOBINL1000</Property>

            <Property name="log.ECONET1000.dir">D:\\Mconnect\\LOGGER\\ECONET1000</Property>
            <Property name="log.AIRTEL1000.dir">D:\\Mconnect\\LOGGER\\AIRTEL1000</Property>
        </Properties>

        <Appenders>
            <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %d [%t] %c: %m%n" />
            </Console>

            <File name="EIGInformation"
                fileName="C:\\EIG_SOURCE_CODE\\EIG_20140901\\logs\\EIGInformation1.log">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>%5p | %m%n</Pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
            </File>

            <!-- Debug logger -->
            <RollingRandomAccessFile name="debugLogger"
                fileName="${log.dir}/mconnectDebugLogger.log"
                filePattern="${log.dir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/mconnectDebugLogger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">

                <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>%5p | %d | %m%n</Pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <!-- <DefaultRolloverStrategy> <Delete basePath="${log.dir}" maxDepth="2"> 
                    <IfFileName glob="*/mconnectDebugLogger-*.log.gz" /> <IfLastModified age="60d" 
                    /> </Delete> </DefaultRolloverStrategy> -->
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="${rotateLogsInterval}" />
                </Policies>
            </RollingRandomAccessFile>
            <!-- Transaction tdr file -->
            <RollingRandomAccessFile name="transactionDetails"
                fileName="${log.dir}/TDR.log"
                filePattern="${log.dir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/TDR-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">

                <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>%5p | %d | %t:: | %m%n</Pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <!-- <DefaultRolloverStrategy> <Delete basePath="${log.dir}" maxDepth="2"> 
                    <IfFileName glob="*/TDR-*.log.gz" /> <IfLastModified age="60d" /> </Delete> 
                    </DefaultRolloverStrategy> -->
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="${rotateLogsInterval}" />
                </Policies>
            </RollingRandomAccessFile>

            <!-- Connect Info General log. -->
            <RollingRandomAccessFile name="connectInfoLogGeneral"
                fileName="${log.INVALIDMNO.dir}/connectInfoLogGeneral.log"
                filePattern="${log.INVALIDMNO.dir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/connectInfoLogGeneral-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">

                <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>%5p | %d | %m%n</Pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <!-- <DefaultRolloverStrategy> <Delete basePath="${log.INVALIDMNO.dir}" 
                    maxDepth="2"> <IfFileName glob="*/connectInfoLogGeneral-*.log.gz" /> <IfLastModified 
                    age="60d" /> </Delete> </DefaultRolloverStrategy> -->
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="${rotateLogsInterval}" />
                </Policies>
            </RollingRandomAccessFile>

            <!-- Connect Process log. -->
            <RollingRandomAccessFile name="connectProcessLogGeneral"
                fileName="${log.INVALIDMNO.dir}/connectProcessLogGeneral.log"
                filePattern="${log.INVALIDMNO.dir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/connectProcessLogGeneral-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>%5p | %d | %m%n</Pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <!-- <DefaultRolloverStrategy> <Delete basePath="${log.log.INVALIDMNO.dir.dir}" 
                    maxDepth="2"> <IfFileName glob="*/connectProcessLogGeneral-*.log.gz" /> <IfLastModified 
                    age="60d" /> </Delete> </DefaultRolloverStrategy> -->
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="${rotateLogsInterval}" />
                </Policies>
            </RollingRandomAccessFile>

            <!-- Connect Info log -->
            <RollingRandomAccessFile name="connectInfoLogMOBINL1000"
                fileName="${log.MOBINL1000.dir}/connectInfoMOBINL1000.log"
                filePattern="${log.MOBINL1000.dir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/connectInfoMOBINL1000-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">

                <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>%5p | %d | %m%n</Pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <!-- <DefaultRolloverStrategy> <Delete basePath="${log.MOBINL1000.dir}" 
                    maxDepth="2"> <IfFileName glob="*/connectInfoMOBINL1000-*.log.gz" /> <IfLastModified 
                    age="60d" /> </Delete> </DefaultRolloverStrategy> -->
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="${rotateLogsInterval}" />
                </Policies>
            </RollingRandomAccessFile>

            <!-- Connect Process log -->
            <RollingRandomAccessFile name="connectProcessLogMOBINL1000"
                fileName="${log.MOBINL1000.dir}/connectProcessMOBINL1000.log"
                filePattern="${log.MOBINL1000.dir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/connectProcessMOBINL1000-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">

                <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>%5p | %d | %m%n</Pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <!-- <DefaultRolloverStrategy> <Delete basePath="${log.MOBINL1000.dir}" 
                    maxDepth="2"> <IfFileName glob="*/connectProcessMOBINL1000-*.log.gz" /> <IfLastModified 
                    age="60d" /> </Delete> </DefaultRolloverStrategy> -->
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="${rotateLogsInterval}" />
                </Policies>
            </RollingRandomAccessFile>


        </Appenders>

        <Loggers>

            <!-- CXF is used heavily by Mule for web services -->
            <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.cxf" level="WARN" />

            <!-- Apache Commons tend to make a lot of noise which can clutter the log -->
            <AsyncLogger name="org.apache" level="INFO" />

            <!-- Reduce startup noise -->
            <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.beans.factory"
                level="WARN" />

            <!-- Mule classes -->
            <AsyncLogger name="org.mule" level="INFO" />
            <AsyncLogger name="com.mulesoft" level="INFO" />


            <AsyncLogger name="EIGInformation" level="INFO">
                <AppenderRef ref="EIGInformation" />
            </AsyncLogger>

            <AsyncLogger
                name="com.comviva.mconnect.webservices.impl.MConnectWebServices"
                level="info">
                <AppenderRef ref="debugLogger" />
            </AsyncLogger>
            <AsyncLogger name="transactionDetails" level="OFF">
                <AppenderRef ref="debugLogger" />
            </AsyncLogger>

            <AsyncLogger name="connectInfoLogGeneral" level="INFO">
                <AppenderRef ref="connectInfoLogGeneral" />
            </AsyncLogger>  
            <AsyncLogger name="connectProcessLogGeneral" level="INFO">
                <AppenderRef ref="connectProcessLogGeneral" />
            </AsyncLogger>

            <AsyncLogger name="connectInfoLogMOBINL1000" level="INFO">
                <AppenderRef ref="connectInfoLogMOBINL1000" />
            </AsyncLogger>
            <AsyncLogger name="connectProcessLogMOBINL1000" level="INFO">
                <AppenderRef ref="connectProcessLogMOBINL1000" />
            </AsyncLogger>

            <AsyncRoot level="INFO">
                <AppenderRef ref="EIGInformation" />
            </AsyncRoot>
        </Loggers>

    </Configuration>



log4j: Using URL [file:/home/contest/prd/muleTomcat/webapps/Connect-1.3.0/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Preferred configurator class: org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator
log4j: System property is :null
log4j: Standard DocumentBuilderFactory search succeded.
log4j: DocumentBuilderFactory is: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl

log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 31
log4j:WARN Document root element "Configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
log4j:WARN Document root element "Configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 31
log4j:WARN Document is invalid: no grammar found.log4j:WARN Document is invalid: no grammar found.

log4j:ERROR DOM element is - not a <log4j:configuration> element.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.mchange.v2.log.MLog).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the old log4j-1.2.x.jar is still in the classpath. Please remove it from the classpath and ensure the following jars are on the classpath:

1. log4j-api-2.x.jar
2. log4j-core-2.x.jar
3. log4j-1.2-api-2.x.jar - this adapter will route logging calls your application makes to the Log4j2 implementation.

I recommend using the most recent Log4j version for 2.x (2.7 as of this writing).

If you're using slf4j, please remove `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12` (this is for the old Log4j 1) and add `org.apache.logging.log4j:slf4j-impl`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I just added mentioned jars into class path and I have removed 1.2 jar but still no luck, I am getting same error as I mentioned in the post. I am using slf4j-api-1.7.7 and slf4j-simple-1.7.7 and I am not using slf4j-log4j12.

Comment: The `"log4j:..."` logs are produced by Log4j 1, so the 1.2 jar must still be on the classpath somewhere... Also, either `log4j-1.2-api-2.x.jar` is not on the classpath or it comes after the Log4j 1.2 jar. You can print `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` to verify.